# In android my facebook url must load in xml page instead it is going onto browser

Tags: android, xml, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am new to this android i have written the code for using facebook in my android app.

to use facebook i have selected a url for a apple fruits salads

https://www.facebook.com/applefruitsalads

i can access the link in android app but it must open in xml page instead it is going to the browser then loading the above URL.

i dont want my app to load it in browser else i need it in xml file.

one more thing i have used webview in xml page such that it will populate the url given onto the webview

i don't have knowledge what to do so can anyone help me . i have pasted the code below

[image]

fbview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fb_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

FbActivity.java

```
package com.coded.sandeep;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class FbActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fb_view);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/applefruitsalads");
       // i dont want to direct to browser instead it has to pop up in xml file only

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.facebook, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

i have added statements in my manifest file as well
[image]

Comment: @rajshree can u help me for this solution

Comment: try my below solution and let me know, it is very short and simple for you to understand.

Comment: ya i will try and let you know in comment @InnocentKiller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package com.coded.sandeep;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class FbActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fb_view);
    mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings settings = mWebview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(FbActivity.this, "", "Loading...",
            true);
    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(FbActivity.this)
                    .create();
            alert.setTitle("No connection"));
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.setMessage("No connection"));
            alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }
    });
    mWebview.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/applefruitsalads");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.facebook, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

Dont forget to add `Internet Permission` in `Manifest`

I hope this will work

Comment: wait i will try and let u know few minutes

Answer (score 0):

apply webviewclient to your webview like

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: i will try and let you know about this @Ketan Ahir

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebview ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mWebview  = new WebView(this);
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
        final Activity activity = this;
        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Error in loading webview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mWebview .loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/applefruitsalads");
        setContentView(mWebview);
    }
}
```

Comment: ya above check the image i have added still i have to add something @InnocentKiller

Comment: I don't get anything properly what actually you want to say, can you clear it please.

Comment: no no nothing i have added internet permission already in manifest file that i have displayed it in the above question form of image sorry for troubling u @InnocentKiller